# CreateRemoteThread works with PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION

Tags: c++, multithreading, dll, privileges, inject

Recently, I've studied dll injection techniques using CreateRemoteThread, and I found something interesting. I just opened the process with PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION and called CreateRemoteThread with its handle. Surprisingly it worked. The funny thing about this, I tried create remote thread in the same way with another function NtCreateThreadEx which is an internal function of CreateRemoteThread and it didn't work.I can't understand what's happening here. The code is as follows:

```
void Create_Remote_Thread()
{
    HMODULE ntdll, kernel32;
    HANDLE hCurrp = nullptr;
    ntdll = GetModuleHandle(L"ntdll.dll");
    kernel32 = LoadLibrary(L"kernel32.dll");
    FARPROC lpfnLoadLibrary = NULL;

    _NtGetNextProcess nextProc = (_NtGetNextProcess)GetProcAddress(ntdll, "NtGetNextProcess");
    
    lpfnLoadLibrary = GetProcAddress(kernel32, "LoadLibraryA");

    char buf[MAX_PATH];
    //while (nextProc(hCurrp, PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION, 0, 0, &hCurrp) == 0) {
    while (nextProc(hCurrp, PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, &hCurrp) == 0) {
        GetModuleFileNameExA(hCurrp, 0, buf, MAX_PATH);
        HANDLE hThread = NULL;
        if (strstr(buf, "notepad.exe") != NULL) {
        
            hThread = CreateRemoteThread(hCurrp, NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)lpfnLoadLibrary, NULL, 0, NULL);      
            
        }
    }
}
```

Then, Can I create remote thread just with lower privilege? If anyone knows about this, please inform me. Thanks.

Comment: And `NtCreateThreadEx` works with `PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS`?

Comment: Of course, it works. I tested it.

Comment: But the `CreateRemoteThread` call you posted can't work, since `lpParameter` is NULL.

Comment: The return value of CreateRemoteThread is not null, I mean, hThread is not null. It means it works despite lpParameter being NULL.